# How to change the font and border color of the Button Component in MD Bootsrap React

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, web-frontend, mdbootstrap

So I'm using a button component from [MDBootrap](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/). To be specific I'm using an [Outline Button Component](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/docs/4.0/bootstrap-components/buttons/#outline-buttons) which looks like this:

[image]

The code that's given on the website for this particular component is as follows:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-warning">Warning</button>
```

I was wondering if there's a way around to change the font color as well as the border color of this button component since at the moment it's not matching well with the theme of my website. Thanks!

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Thank you so much :-) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to reuse styles, create a new css class:

```
.btn.my-cusomized-button {
    border-color: pink;
    color: pink;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 1px solid pink;
}
```

```
<button
  type="button"
  class="btn my-cusomized-button"
>
  Primary
</button>
```

n.b. css class `my-cusomized-button` and `pink` as color are just an example. Use your colors and class which better suits your need